# What is it called when you write what someone is saying?

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine you're sitting in the corner, writing down a conversation that is occurring in the middle of the room. What are you doing?

"Copying down" is what I'm using, but it seems like there should be a better word.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are taking it down verbatim, you are **transcribing** it, and the finished product is a **transcription**. It you are just making notes of the gist of the conversation, you are **taking a record** of it.

Comment: In the US, that would be _making_ a record of it. _Taking it down (in writing/shorthand/IPA)_ usually refers to transcription, and _taking a record_ sounds to my ears like a phrase out of "Prime Suspect".

Comment: _Make a record_ is also possible in BrEng, but _take the record_ of, say, a meeting is used in the British public service.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are being a stenographer without knowing stenography well enough to use stenography or shorthand.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other possible answers given here, you could be said to be **taking dictation.**

Comment: Can you be said to be 'taking dictation' if the speaker is not actually 'dictating' but, let's say, having a conversation with someone?

Comment: @WS2 - I would just call that 'transcription'.

Comment: Which is not 'dictation'!

Comment: @WS2 - The questioner's wording did not preclude a setting like a courtroom or formal hearing where the proceedings are supposed to be recorded. In such a case, 'dictation' is not excluded as a possible description.

Comment: Are you telling me that the learned Judge is dictating notes to a stenographer? What a temerarious suggestion! The bewigged silks of the High Court of Justice in London would not be amused! Surely the Judge is addressing the Court, and the 'unlearned' clerk is dutifully recording/transcribing  his utterances.

Comment: @WS2, "dictation" can be used pretty loosely, [*"wrote my first poem at the age of four or five, my mother taking it down to dictation"*](http://www.orwell.ru/library/essays/wiw/english/e_wiw).